# How can I keep sensitive data out of logs?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How can I keep sensitive data out of logs?

Currently I have an exception which is raised in a method A. In method B this exception is re-raised adding further information. In method C I want to log the exception with a further information.

My first attempt was to add a string replace method before logging the exception, but this does not affect the whole traceback. Especially because I call the Python library request in methodA. The first exception takes place in this library.

- first excepton in requests: urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
- second exception in requests: requests.exceptions.ProxyError

Both exceptions within the request library contain already the sensitive data in the traceback.

```py
def methodA():
   try:
       connect_to_http_with_request_lib()
   except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as err:
     raise MyExceptionA(f"this log contains sensitive info in err: {err}") 

def methodB():
   try: 
     methodA()
   except MyExceptionA as err:
     raise MyExceptionB (f"add some more info to: {err}")
 
def methodC(): 
   try: 
     methodB()
     return True
   except MyExceptionB as err: 
     err = re.sub(r"(?is)password=.+", "password=xxxx", str(err))
     logger.exception(f("methodB failed exception {err}")
     return False
```

How can I parse the whole traceback before logging the exception in order to mask out sensitive data?
I use loguru as logging library.

The Django framework seems to address the same problem with their own methods. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/error-reporting/)